# Python turtle module causes OS X to crash

Tags: python, macos, turtle-graphics

I'm working through [Think Python](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/thinkpython2.pdf) chapter 4, where they tell you to type the following to see if you have the turtle module:

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
```

This is supposed to open a new window, but instead, it crashes my computer. I've seen it freeze my computer where I can't move the cursor or change windows, and I have to restart it. And I've also seen it close all my programs and re-open them.

I'm running Python 3.7 downloaded from Anaconda on a Macbook Air with Mojave version 10.14.6.

EDIT: When I run BenajahTX's suggestion below, I get this error message printed 16 times:
`CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459`

Any clue what is causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting when it crashes?

Comment: I don't get an error message. My computer will either freeze immediately and I have to force a restart or it closes all my programs. When I go back to the terminal, it says it was restored (e.g. [Restored Aug 12, 2019 at 10:44:28 AM]), but no error message.

Comment: Actually, just tried BenajahTX's suggestion below, and got an error message:

python[1808:86486] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459

Comment: It seems to be a bug in `macOS`. There are others that report similar behavior when using `tkinter` and/or `py2app`.

Comment: Did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: Oh I solved by reinstalling Anaconda. Probably updating everything would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

try and set the screen and mainloop

```
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.setup(width,height)
    while True:
            window.update()
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried this, first in interactive mode, then in a script. In interactive mode, when I tried window = turtle.Screen(), it immediately restarted my computer. When I ran the entirety of what you suggested as a script, it also restarted my computer, but now I see this error message in the terminal printed 16 times: python[1808:86486] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459

Answer (score 0):

Try running the file in the terminal using the command:-
$ python filename.py

I had the same issue and I was VS code extension Code Runner to run the python file, however, when I tried the terminal it worked and the mac OS was not crashing this time